# livequery - confirm()

Tags: javascript, jquery, confirm, livequery

I don't get why this confirm() call fires up even though i hit "no". Can you tell me what i'm doing wrong?

```
$('.deleteButton').livequery('click',function(){
        if(confirm('Are you sure?')){
            return true;
        }else
        {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    });
```

The HTML Markup:

```
<a class="smallbutton deleteButton" href="users.php?todo=delete&id=32">delete</a>
```

I checked and it does return false, but the page still redirects to the clicked A href value. Normally, if i return false, it shouldn't, right?

Comment: can you include the code HTML?

Comment: Is the anchor tag and .deleteButton the same element?

Comment: just updated the question with the html markup. @jstayton: yes

Comment: The usage of "livequery" indicates you're using an older version of jQuery, along with the livequery plugin. Is that the case? If you can, consider using newer jQuery (if that does not cause problems) and using the "live" method instead. Also, it's possible what you're getting is simply the result of the javascript failing entirely. The JS fails, the default behavior occurs. Do you get JS errors in the Error Console with this code when viewing in Firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize: it turns out i was attaching another behaviour to all anchors inside the main content container. I added an exclusion clause for deleteButton and it works fine now.

Here is my final, working, code:

```
var $tabs= $("#tabs").tabs({
        fx: {
            opacity: 'toggle'
        },
        load: function(event, ui) { 

            $('a', ui.panel).livequery('click',function() {

                // we need to exclude the listNav buttons AND deleteButton buttons from this behavior

                if($(this).parent().is(':not(".ln-letters")') && $(this).is(':not(".deleteButton")')){

                    $(ui.panel).load(this.href);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

And the delete button behaviour works with a simple:

```
$('.deleteButton').live('click',function(e){
    return confirm('Are you sure?');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a id="myId_1" href="#" class="deleteButton">delete</a>

$('.deleteButton').livequery('click',function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        if(confirm('Are you sure?')){
            functionForDelete($(this).attr("id").split("_")[1]);
        }
});

// OR ir you like goto href

<a id="myId1" href="url/delete/id.php?1" class="deleteButton">delete</a>
$('.deleteButton').livequery('click',function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        if(confirm('Are you sure?')){
            window.location=$(this).attr("href");
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change livequery() to live(). jQuery supports the same functionality. Just tested in FF and it worked with live() but never even gave me a prompt with livequery()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.deleteButton').livequery('click',function(e){
    if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        return true;
    } else {
        if (e.preventDefault) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            e.returnValue = false;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you need function(e).

Comment: Oh sorry, yes:
    livequery('click',function(e){